# Extrange error when passing a variable as reference to a thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to make a few threads to calculate average, minimum, maximun and standard deviation at the same time.

Like this (T is a 100 size double array):

```
P[0] = thread(&average, T, ref(average));
P[0].join();
P[1] = thread(&maxmin, T, ref(max), ref(min)),
P[2] = thread(&standardDev, T, ref(stdDev),ref(average));

P[1].join();
P[2].join();
```

And in the method:

```
void average(double* T, double &average) {
double sum=0.0;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    sum +=T[i];
}
average = sum/100;  
}
```

Then I compile it with:

```
g++ -pthread -std=c++11 (filename) -o (name)
```

But it fails and shows this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:39:0,
             from ejercicio_4.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<double*(double*, std::reference_wrapper<double>)>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:137:47:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = double*; _Args = {double (&)[100], std::reference_wrapper<double>}]’
ejercicio_4.cpp:89:40:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1697:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<double*(double*, std::reference_wrapper<double>)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1727:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<double*(double*, std::reference_wrapper<double>)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^
```

I have g++ 4.8, so it should work with threads, I don't know what's causing this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal test case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo or maybe a name collision on first line, where you are passing as second argument the name of the function (`average`) rather than the name of a target variable. What you probably meant to write was:

```
double avg;
P[0] = thread(&average, T, ref(avg));
```

Comment: Probably that's not a typo but name collision

Comment: WOAH! That was it! I can't believe I missed that, I was so sure that it was a reference error that I didn't realize, thank you!!